# How to forward positional and keyword arguments in Julia?

Tags: syntax, julia

In Python we can do:

```py
def foo(*args, **kargs):
    return bar(*args, **kargs)
```

Is it possible to forward positional and keyword arguments in Julia?

Comment: That question helps clarify a question I have had.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep:

```
julia> function p(args...; kwargs...) println("args:", args, " kwargs:", kwargs) end;

julia> function f(args...; kwargs...) p(args...; kwargs...); end;

julia> p(1,2,a="AA",b="BB")
args:(1,2) kwargs:{(:a,"AA"),(:b,"BB")}

julia> f(1,2,a="AA",b="BB")
args:(1,2) kwargs:{(:a,"AA"),(:b,"BB")}
```

(I don't know enough Julia to know the conventional names for `args` and `kwargs`.)

Comment: Strange, I've probably mistyped ',' and ';' during my attempt in the REPL. Thanks.